# Graph Traversal & Filtering with Gremlin using OrientDB

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

```
Group[code=a]->Choice[selected=true]
Group[code=a]->Choice[selected=false]
Group[code=a]->Choice[selected=false]
Group[code=b]->Choice[selected=false]
Group[code=b]->Choice[selected=false]
Group[code=c]->Choice[selected=false]
Group[code=c]->Choice[selected=true]
```

Given the above Vertices, I'm looking to query for Group Vertices, where a group does not have any Choice vertices, with a selected attribute as true.

Hence the result should return only Group b

```
Group[code=b]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your graph - when asking questions about Gremlin it's always helpful to provide your sample data in this way:

```
graph = TinkerGraph.open()
g = graph.traversal()
g.addV('group').property('code','a').as('a').
  addV('group').property('code','b').as('b').
  addV('group').property('code','c').as('c').
  addV('choice').property('selected',true).
  addE('link').from('a').
  addV('choice').property('selected',false).
  addE('link').from('a').
  addV('choice').property('selected',false).
  addE('link').from('a').
  addV('choice').property('selected',false).
  addE('link').from('b').
  addV('choice').property('selected',false).
  addE('link').from('b').
  addV('choice').property('selected',false).
  addE('link').from('c').
  addV('choice').property('selected',true).
  addE('link').from('c').iterate()
```

One way to get the answer you want is to do a traversal like this:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('group').
......1>   where(__.not(out('link').has('selected',true))).
......2>   values('code')
==>b
```

The above answer is for TinkerPop 3.x. In TinkerPop 2.x the pattern is the same. You would basically do:

```
g.V().has('label','group').filter{ it._().out('link').has('selected',true).hasNext() }
```

Comment: Thanks! - While this would work in Tinkerpop 3, I was looking for a solution using Tinkerpop 2x , as the OrientDB community version is still supporting the older tinkerpop spec..

Comment: My 2.x knowledge is shaky, but the pattern is roughly the same. Updated my answer to include 2.x and also made an additional improvement on the 3.x answer. The traversal now stops as soon as it hits the first `true` rather than iterating all the adjacent vertices looking and potentially finding multiple true.